# Interpolate on ocean data points without considering land points using Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation

I have some ocean data points, and I am trying to interpolate them to create a raster. After interpolating with IDW, the land area is also filled with data. How can I only interpolate the data on the ocean area and not on land. I need the land area to remain with no data.

Comment: Do you have a polygon with your land area? You could rasterize that, set the cell values to no data, then mosaic it into your IDW raster.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the polygon and it worked well, but some area near the land donot have the value, Do you know How do I to solve this problem?

Comment: If mask then interpolate is leaving blank spaces you could try interpolating first then masking. However be aware that the values in these formerly blanks areas may not be very accurate.